# Need linux device driver to re-scan devices after hardware reconfigure

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a device driver that is used to control a tester system connected to an x86 based workstation via a PCIe GEN2 x16 cable link. The tester system consists of a fabric of PCIe switches (Avago, formerly PLX), resulting in a slot based system of up to 40 instruments, each instrument is a PCIe device on its own, driven by 4 PCIe lanes (the PCIE switches take the x16 link and break it down to 40 individual PCIe links). This results in up to 100 PCI buses being part of the fabric. This is well within the PCI spec of 256 buses max.

The issue we have is that some motherboard's have a broken BIOS and with a fully populated tester, the BIOS will not POST properly and the workstation fails to boot (it doesn't even get to the BIOS splash screen). In order to get around this problem, we have our hardware's PCIe switches initially configured to "hide" most of the PCIe fabric using the virtual switch capability that the Avago PCIe switches have (if anyone wants details, please ask). This allows the BIOS to boot since only a few buses are visible st this time. Our driver, when it loads, detects this mode, then writes to the PCIe switch configuration registers to make the entire fabric visible.

It then calls pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device on the top level PCIe switch, then using a reference to the parent bus device, tells it to rescan the bus (pci_rescan_bus). The issue here is that where there were initially just a few buses on this switch, there are now dozens. If some other bus or device originally existed higher than our tester fabric, the rescan apparently is not smart enough to realize that it can't allocate these new buses over on top of previously existing devices.

For example, initially our minimized fabric sits at bus 2, its secondary bus is assigned bus 3, and the underlying fabric extends to bus 8. Then perhaps there is another root port on the motherboard with onboard device or plug in slot card that is at bus 9 and 10.

Now when we "unhide" our fabric, and make 40 more buses visible and rescan, it does not relocate the starting point above the existing devices at bus 9 and 10, it start re-allocating them from 2, ranging up to 42, overlaying on top of the devices at 9 and 10. This is illegal. What we did for Centos 6 (Linux kernel 2.6.32) was to re-write the pci_bus structure and config registers to move the primary, secondary, and subordinate buses of the parent port to a range above the existing devices, in the above example that would be starting at bus 11 before the rescan. This worked beautifully under Centos (RHEL) 6, but doesn't work on Centos (RHEL 7) kernel 3.10.0. It appears that the pci_bus structure for holding secondary and subordinate numbers were changed to some kind of internal resource. Even though I changed the numbers in the resource, when I call pci_rescan_bus the kernel crashes (apparently, the whole thing freezes). It may be related to the management of these resource objects, but they appear to be internal and not externally modifiable.

Sorry for the long winded explanation, but it is all pertinent. My basic question is how can I re-enumerate my expanded PCIe fabric properly and legally using a free range of PCI bus numbers?